# JQuery Validate plugin submitting when it shouldn't

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate my form by printing out a message if the email is invalid, if the password does not meet minimum requirements or if the password and confirm password fields do not match.

To verify the plugin is working correctly, I am only testing for the validity of the email. The validator seems to be working for a second before the form is submitted regardless of whether the form is valid or not and I can't seem to figure out why.

Also, the 'email isn't valid' message isn't being printed out.

I have been trying to figure this one out for quite some time and I appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

JavaScript:

```
$('#signUpForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    }
});

$('#signUpForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).valid()){
        $(this).submit();
    }else{
        return false;
    }           
});
```

Form:

```
<form id="signUpForm" method="post" action="signup.php">
    <input id="signUpEmail" name="email" class="form-control"> 
    <input id="signUpPassword" name="password" class="form-control" type="password"> 
    <input id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" class="form-control" type="password"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Refer to [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org) and [SO Tag Wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) for proper usage.

Comment: @Sparky, Thanks for the reply. please see updated code, the outcome is the same.

Comment: Your "updated" code is working fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/2t7dbuuf/

Comment: This is weird, the updated question has the correct answer..

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is all wrong...

```
$('#signUpForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    ....
});

$('#signUpForm').submit(function(e){
    ....     
});
```

Your `.submit()` handler is totally redundant and totally interfering with the proper operation of the jQuery Validate plugin, which automatically captures the button `click` and blocks the `submit` event already.

In other words, the code within your `.submit()` handler is functionally identical to what the plugin is already doing for you.  You don't need it and it's breaking validation.

---

Your `errorPlacment` callback function is empty so that's going to stop all error messages from displaying...

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
```

---

It should simply look something like this...

```
$('#signUpForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8,
            maxlength: 12
        },
        confirmPassword: {
            equalTo: '#signUpPassword'
        }
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/2t7dbuuf/**

---

Refer to [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org) and [SO Tag Wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) for proper usage.

Comment: Thanks Sparky, although the problem remains. The validation works for a second, then the form is submitted regardless of if the form is valid or not.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend, Can you reproduce the issue in a jsFiddle?  Otherwise, the code as you "updated" it is working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/2t7dbuuf/

Comment: Although I was unable to reproduce it in jsfiddle. I found the cause, the issue is due to me using the paypal payment gateway called braintree, which requires certain input fields to **not** have a `name` attribute. Instead, the input attribute is called `data-braintree-name`. Upon removing these input fields for testing, the validation works, although these payment gateway fields are required for my application, so I am sort of stuck at the moment :/

Comment: @AnchovyLegend, respectfully, that has nothing to do with anything you've shown in your OP.  However, I can tell you that the jQuery Validate plugin cannot work if any input element does not have a unique `name` attribute.  It's an internal, hard-coded limitation without a workaround.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend,  you could programmatically copy the data into hidden input elements (each with a `name`) and then validate these hidden elements. You'll just have to enable validation of hidden fields ( `ignore: []` ), and then adjust message placement with the `errorPlacement` callback function.