# Jquery validation showing message but form submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jquery validation: The validation message is working well. But, when i click submit, the form is being submitted. 
This is what i used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#register-form").validate({
        rules: 
            {
                mobile:{number:true,required:true,maxlength:10},
                phone:{number:true,required:true,maxlength:10},
                office_phone:{number:true,required:true,maxlength:10},
                father_name:{required:true},
                mother_name:{required:true},
                dob:{required:true,date:true},
                gender:{required:true},

                name:{required:true},

                email:{required:true,
                        remote:
                          {
                                url: "{{url('/checkEmail')}}",
                                type: "post",
                          }
                      },

                password : {
                        minlength : 8
                    },
                    password_confirmation : {
                        minlength : 8,
                        equalTo : "#password",
                    },


            },
            messages:
            {
                email:{required:'Email is required.',
                      remote:'Email already in use',
                     },
                phone:{required:'Phone Number is required.', number:'Only Numbers allowed,',maxlength:'Phone Number should be maximum of 10 digits'},
                office_phone:{required:'Phone Number is required.', number:'Only Numbers allowed,',maxlength:'Phone Number should be maximum of 10 digits'},
                mobile:{required:'Phone Number is required.', number:'Only Numbers allowed,',maxlength:'Phone Number should be maximum of 10 digits'},
            },

        });
});
```

I tried with

```
$(document).on('submit', '#register-form', function (e) 
{   
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#register-form").validate({
    rules: 
    .....
```

This is not submitting the form but not showing error messages too. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: e.preventDefault(); is not allowing the form submit.

Comment: `$('#register-form').validate()` is an initializer for the validator plugin. You have to do it outside of the form submit, after the DOM is ready. You're likely running into an issue where you're running `.validate()` before the DOM is ready, can you update your question with where you're calling `$('#register-form').validate()`?

Comment: Call `$('#register-form').valid()` with invalid input. Does it return true?

Comment: @Daniel With invalid input it is showing messages, but the form can be submitted.

Comment: Use `$('#register-form').on('submit', function() { if (!$(this).valid()) { e.preventDefault(); });`.

Comment: @Daniel should it supposed to be preventing the form submission even without using that?

Comment: No, if it's doing that, then you need to remove the `$(document).on('submit')` block and only keep the `$('#register-form').on('submit')` block.

Comment: @Daniel I mean not using on submit at all and only with `$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#register-form").validate({
        rules: 
            {`

Comment: i've followed this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28329789/5928946 and working jsfiddle. my code is exactly similar.  still i'm wondering what i did wrong?

Comment: `.validate()` is where you configure the options for the validation plugin. If you're trying to configure the form submit cancellation there as well, I think you can make use of the `invalidHandler` function: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#invalidhandler like so: `invalidHandler: function(event, validator) { if (!validator.isValid()) { e.preventDefault(); }`.

Comment: @Daniel Ok, but this exact working fiddle is also not working. http://jsfiddle.net/2t7dbuuf/ no errors in console. Also required in input field  doesnot work with this script added. Can something wrong with form cause this?

Comment: @Daniel I figured it out. but still don't know why? i have `<input type="checkbox" required> I agree to the <a href="">Terms and Conditions</a>` just before the form which is all responsible for this, How about this?

Answer (score 0):

use 1st one

```
$("#register-form").validate({
rules:{
//rules here
},
messages:{
//messages here
},
submitHandler: function(form)
{
form.submit(); 
}
});
```

Comment: the form submits without validation.

Comment: Are you write rules?